# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'isnull'

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to remove the empty rows. But when I try to count empty lines to see if it worked, I have an error:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'isnull'

**My script:**

```
import pandas
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('data.csv', sep=';')

#print('Table Data\n', data)

data_sum_empty = data.isnull().sum()
#print(data_sum_empty)

data_not_empty = data_sum_empty.dropna(how = 'all', inplace = True)
print(data_not_empty.isnull().sum())
```

**Output:**

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File ".\data_vis.py", line 12, in 
>       print(data_not_empty.isnull().sum())
>
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'isnull'

**Some data**

```
flightID        DepTime  ArrTime ActualElapsedTime  AirTime  ArrDelay
BBYYEUVY67527   1416.0   1514.0               58.0     39.0      64.0   
MUPXAQFN40227   2137.0     37.0              120.0     47.0      52.0   
LQLYUIMN79169    730.0    916.0              166.0    143.0     -25.0   
KTAMHIFO10843      NaN      NaN                NaN      NaN       NaN   
BOOXJTEY23623      NaN      NaN                NaN      NaN       NaN
```

**Why duplicate???? I did not know the problem was because of the inplace. If I'd known, I would not have asked!**

Comment: Did you print data_not_empty and check

Comment: Marking a question as a duplicate isn't a punishment for the questioner, it's a boon.. you get to see a Q&A which has been viewed 3,000+ times with useful comments and a good answer. Embrace it!

Answer (score 4):

When you do an operation on a df with `inplace=True`, the variable or output of that operation is None.

```
data_sum_empty.dropna(how = 'all', inplace = True)
data_not_empty = data_sum_empty.copy()
print(data_not_empty.isnull().sum())
```

Or

```
data_not_empty = data_sum_empty.dropna(how = 'all')
print(data_not_empty.isnull().sum())
```

Answer (score 3):

Do not reassign if you use inplace = True:

```
data_not_empty = data_sum_empty.dropna(how = 'all')
print(data_not_empty.isnull().sum())
```